# Apipa/dhcp table

Tags: networking, zeroconf

I had been working with a friend's router and came across a curiousoity Google can't answer.

On an arris mta with router combo, it appears that the dhcp is recognizing a 169.254 address.

From what I know, Apipa addressing should only occur if the device is unable to get a dhcpack. If thats the case, why would it show in the routers device table if it can't be place on the same network?

Comment: "the dhcp is recognizing a 169.254 address" could you explain what you mean by this?  DHCP is "recognizing" it in what way?

Comment: From the gui, The dhcp/connected devices section lists devices that are connected through the router. The devices show with a mac address/lease time/up address.